# [Python|Netmiko]Use a custom ssh_agent in netmiko connectHandler

Tags: python, netmiko

I am using Python/netmiko to automate ssh into a linux server and fire few commands. The catch is that this box needs a custom ssh agent running in a specific path to be used for logging in, my existing ConnectHandler which uses the default ssh agent($SSH_AUTH_SOCK)

My ConnectHandler,

```
   connect_params = {
        "device_type": "terminal_server",
        "host": host1,
        "username": getpass.getuser(),
        "use_keys": True,
        "allow_agent": True,
        "conn_timeout": 80,
        "banner_timeout": 80,
        "session_log": "output.txt",
    }
```

This works for devices which does not need a custom handler but fails for my current linux box, my path for the custom agent is '~/Library/Application Support/custom-ssh-agent/agent.sock'. Can you help in understanding how I can pass the custom ssh-agent path into connect handler?